# что такое pip install и что означают слова "поставить Питон пакет"

Tags: python-3.x

будьте добры, объясните пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1):

pip - это система управления пакетами, которая используется для установки и управления программными пакетами, написанными на Python.

То есть благодаря pip вы можете устранить зависимости (если используете готовые исходники чьего-то проекта и собираетесь собрать его).

Но прежде, чем использовать pip его, конечно же, нужно установить. В интернете полно документации как на русском так и на английском языке.

> Поставить питон пакет

Означает, что для сборки данного продукта требуется определенная зависимость и решить её можно с помощью pip

Comment: А еще pip часто идет в комплекте с питоном, его нужно просто найти. Например, для windows его искать нужно в папке `Scripts`, т.е. путь может быть `C:\Python34\Scripts`, а чтобы его можно было вызывать из консоли как `> pip`, а не с полным путем `> C:\Python34\Scripts\pip`, нужно в переменных средах в `Path` добавить путь к папке `Scripts` и после перезапуска консоли pip сразу будет находиться

Comment: @gil9red ничего ставить не надо: как Питон 2 так и Питон 3 поставляются с pip. Если при установке путь к Scripts не прописан, то можно `py -mpip` использовать, чтобы pip запустить.

Comment: @jfs я так и написал, или вас смутило слово "часто"? Не помню точно где, но вроде бы на Raspberry Pi у python 3.5 не было pip, пришлось устанавливать каким setup-скриптом питона. В том скрипте еще внутри в байтовом виде архив с pip находится :)

Comment: @gil9red  я пояснил для людей таких как я, которые могли вас не так понять. В тех случаях, когда  pip при распространении изымается из дистрибуции python, следует родные средства для платформы использовать, к примеру python3-pip пакет